# Illegal reflective acces al iniciar mi proyecto en Eclipse JEE con Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, struts2

recien comienzo en la programacion y  tengo un problema con el tomcat 8.5 o 9.0 al iniciar mis proyectos, uso jdk 12.0.1

y me sale el siguiente error :

```
 WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
    WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase (file:/C:/Users/Valdivia/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.5.42/lib/catalina.jar) to field java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches.localDescs
    WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase
    WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
    WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

he tratado de probar de borrar y volver a poner el tomcat pero sigue saliendo, lo único que creo que pudo haber sido es que copie las librerías de struts2 de otro proyecto en mi carpeta lib.

Comment: es un warning que sale en algunas librerías a partir de Java9 que indica que en algún momento la forma de hacer reflexión que usa alguna de tus librerías ya no se permitirá, sucede mucho con spring